# Google form submit to trigger curated html email response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm trying to have a google form being submitted to trigger an email sent with curated data from that form. I've been all over the internet and can't work this one out. Right now I have:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
var responses = e.namedValues;
var timestamp = responses.Timestamp[0];
var email = responses['Email Address'][0].trim();
var prefer = responses.Name[0].trim();
var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1wwHi6bz9FpStb65g-wbb3joDsAAH7Fnn');
var emailLook = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email2");
emailLook.prefer = prefer;
var htmlMessage = emailLook.evaluate().getContent();
var subject = "Subject";
var body = "Body no html";

GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
htmlBody: htmlMessage,
attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
});
}
```

I can't work out why the email won't send, but I get a "message is not defined" error... Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the question? and where's the template?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: About `but I get a "message is not defined" error`, if this error message is the correct error message you got, I'm worried that in this case, in your script except your showing script, the variable of `message` might be used without declaring `message`. So can you confirm this, again?

Comment: ReferenceError: "message" is not defined. 
at onFormSubmit(Code:34)
I did "//" for all the lines of code and I believe it's something to do with htmlMessage, but even when I just make htmlMessage = "test", I still get an error

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot imagine your current script for replicating your issue. So can you provide your whole script for correctly replicating your current issue of `ReferenceError: "message" is not defined. at onFormSubmit(Code:34)`? By this, I would like to confirm it. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Hi Tanaike,
Thanks for helping. I have run logger and the HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email2") is the part that is not working, do you have an idea why my email2.html would not be imported?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I have run logger and the HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email2") is the part that is not working, do you have an idea why my email2.html would not be imported?`, I had thought that your issue was `but I get a "message is not defined" error`. Is my understanding correct? I'm confused your current situation. I apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand your current situation, can I ask you about the detail of your current situation?

Comment: have you tried instead of using the html template in the options, change it for the body? I will be something like `GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, htmlBody: htmlMessage, {
attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
});
}`